# JAXB @XmlElements Order

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

```
@XmlElements({
     @XmlElement(name = "house", type = House.class),
     @XmlElement(name = "error", type = Error.class),
     @XmlElement(name = "message", type = Message.class),
     @XmlElement(name = "animal", type = Animal.class)     
 })
protected List<RootObject> root;
```

where RootObject is super class of House,Error,Message,Animal

```
root.add(new Animal());
root.add(new Message());
root.add(new Animal());
root.add(new House());
//Prints to xml
<animal/>
<message/>
<animal/>
<house/>
```

but needs in order as declared inside `@XmlElements({})`

```
<house/>
<message/>
<animal/>
<animal/>
```

Comment: `@XmlElements` is just acts as a container to have multiple `@XmlElement`.   Can you elaborately mention your actual need and with Code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What `@XmlElements` is For

`@XmlElements` corresponds to the `choice` structure in XML Schema.  A property corresponds to more than one element (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-xsd-choice-xmlelements.html)

### Collection Order

A JAXB implementation will honor the order the items have been added to the `List`.  This matches the behaviour you are seeing.

### Getting the Desired Order

1. You can add the items to the `List` in the order you want to see them appear in the XML document.
2. You can have separate properties corresponding to each element and then use `propOrder` on `@XmlType` to order the output (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxbs-xmltype-and-proporder.html)
3. Sort the `List` property on a JAXB `beforeMarshal` event.

Comment: So is there a way to achieve the order in Collection ?

Comment: @userG - I have updated my answer with a couple ways to get the desired ordering.

Comment: Is there any other way using Collection Tree to sort object on  void beforeMarshal(Marshaller marshaller) listener ?

Comment: @userG - Yes you could do that. I have updated my answer to include that approach.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved using Comparator :

```
static final Comparator<RootObject> ROOTELEMENT_ORDER = 
                                    new Comparator<RootObject>() {

        final List<Class<? extends RootObject>> classList = Arrays.asList(  
House.class,Error.class, Message.class, Animal.class );                                            

public int compare(RootObject r1, RootObject r2) {
    int i1 = classList.indexOf(r1.getClass());
    int i2 = classList.indexOf(r2.getClass());
    return i1-i2 ;
}
};
  void beforeMarshal(Marshaller marshaller ) {
           Collections.sort(root, ROOTELEMENT_ORDER);    
}
```